# column selection

Tags: shell, scripting

I need to collect the lines where at least one value in the columns A, B, D, E is not equal to 0 (zero).

Below one is the data:

```
                   A      B     C           D        E       G       
ES-N    .    |     0      0     12  |       0        0      100
SES-N   .    |     1      0     10  |       0        0       10
UAS-N   .    |     0      0     10  |       0        0       10
CSS-N   .    |     0      0     10  |       0        5       10
BBE-N   .    |     0      0     15  |       0        0      125
```

Required output:

```
                   A      B     C           D        E       G       
SES-N   .    |     1      0     10  |       0        0       10
CSS-N   .    |     0      0     10  |       0        5       10
```

Could you please provide a shell script which can work in unix platform.

I did below but not eliminated the "0" because of C and G column.

```
#lin is the count of line in the file
for  (( i=1; i<=$lin; i++ ));
do
sed -n -e ""$((ini + 1)),$fin"p"  /file
egrep '1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9' /file1
if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]
then
sed -n -e ""$ini"p" /file
```

Comment: Do you mean you need to collect  the lines where A AND B AND  D AND  E value is not equal to 0 (zero). or to collect  the lines where A OR B OR  D OR  E value is not equal to 0 (zero).

Answer (score 5):

Using awk:

```
awk -n '$4 !=0 || $5 != 0 || $8 != 0 || $9 != 0 {print $0}' filename
```

Answer (score 0):

simply you can also do:

```
awk '$4+$5+$8+$9' infile
```

and to keep header line:

```
awk 'NR==1 || $4+$5+$8+$9' infile
```

Answer (score 0):

@unxnut's `awk` solution is more flexible, but in your particular case, because your requirements are simple, and the file format is also simple, `grep` can do this as well.

To include lines where at least one value is non-zero, is the same thing as to exclude lines where all of those values are zero.  This `grep` command looks for lines that contain two instances of:

- vertical bar followed by whitespace
- zero followed by whitespace
- another zero followed by whitespace

Any line that matches two instances of that pattern (that is, any line where all four values are zero) is **removed**.  The remaining lines are displayed:

```
$ egrep -v '(\|  *0  *0 .*){2}' infile
                   A      B     C           D        E       G       
SES-N   .    |     1      0     10  |       0        0       10
CSS-N   .    |     0      0     10  |       0        5       10
```